# prestashop adminpanel doesnt get after update or upgrade of the system

Tags: php

i have obtained this error on installing prestashop. My php version when its done is php 7.0 but when it updates it shows like this but the admin panel has only this problem occures

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/controller/AdminController.php:2151
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/controller/AdminController.php(2115):
>   AdminControllerCore->filterTabModuleList() #1
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/controller/AdminController.php(1598):
>   AdminControllerCore->addToolBarModulesListButton() #2
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/controller/AdminController.php(2030):
>   AdminControllerCore->initToolbar() #3
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/controllers/admin/AdminLoginController.php(136):
>   AdminControllerCore->initContent() #4
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/controller/Controller.php(189):
>   AdminLoginControllerCore->initContent() #5
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/Dispatcher.php(367):
>   ControllerCore->run() #6
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/admin1/index.php(58):
>   DispatcherCore->dispatch() #7 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/prestashop6/prestashop/classes/controller/AdminController.php
>   on line 2151

Can someone help me to understand why this error happens?

Comment: The php currently in use in your server doesn't have simplexml extension.
Try phpinfo to confirm if it's missing.

Comment: this is shown in php info page SimpleXML  Sterling Hughes, Marcus Boerger, Rob Richards

Comment: i installed simplexml but it doesnt work